# LineChart Date Column Not Working - a[jc] is not a function - Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization, linechart

I wish Google Charts error messages were a little more clear. I'm getting the following error:

> Chart not displayed due to error: a[jc] is not a function. Full error object follows.

In the object that follows it doesn't give much additional information.

My columns are specified like this:

```
chartData.data.cols = [
        {
            id: "some-date",
            label: "Date",
            type: "datetime",
        },
        {
            id: "somenumber",
            label: "Some Number",
            type: "number",
        },

    ];
```

And my rows are created like this:

```
var dateObject = new Date("2014-12-06T10:30:00-0800");
var newRow = {
            c: [
                {
                    v: dateObject,
                },
                {
                    v: arrayItem.predicted_dst,
                },

            ],
}
```

My options.haxis is:

```
hAxis: {
        title: "Default hAxis Title",
        titleTextStyle: {
          color: '#728292', //$darkGreyAccent
        },

        textStyle: {
          color: '#728292', //$darkGreyAccent
        },
        gridlines: {
          color: '#ECF0F1', //$lightGreyAccent'
          count: -1,
        },
        direction: -1,
        baseline: 1,
        baselineColor: '#ECF0F1', //$lightGreyAccent
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to solve this problem so I thought I'd post the situation. It turns out that the baseline:1 was causing the issue.

In my code the baseline 1 was in there as a default for the many other charts I've been creating.

My options now look like this:

```
hAxis: {
        title: "Default hAxis Title",
        titleTextStyle: {
          color: '#728292', //$darkGreyAccent
        },

        textStyle: {
          color: '#728292', //$darkGreyAccent
        },
        gridlines: {
          color: '#ECF0F1', //$lightGreyAccent'
          count: -1,
        },
        direction: -1,
        baselineColor: '#ECF0F1', //$lightGreyAccent
      },
```

I'm not sure why the Google Chart error message is so cryptic, but if anyone else gets this error